# Unable to increase Google piechart width

Tags: jquery, css, google-pie-chart

i am trying created to google pie-chart this pie chart increase circle height and width but my case hole div size is increase
html:-

```
<div id="RedFlagChart" class="square2">
                    </div>
```

css:-

```
 #RedFlagChart {
        width: 800px;
        height: 800px;
        position: absolute;
        top: -30px;
        left: -30px;
}
```

Comment: can you explain **but my case hole div size is increase html**

Comment: Your source does not demonstrate the problem; you should try creating a [mcve]. But are you attempting to change the height to width ratio? That is not possible with SVG.

Comment: @madalinivascu i want to increase the size of the circle inside the div , not the div

Comment: @madalinivascu thanks you sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the `chartArea` property set the desired height and width

`chartArea:{left:20,top:0,width:'50%',height:'75%'}`

more info in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart)

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ycwvnmsq/1/)